# “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am receiving this error in an app I inherited.

I am not sure what I am supposed to do without breaking the app. I have been told that the version that the app was developed in was Swift 3.0. I am also getting `"Click update to change your target's build settings to use the latest Swift syntax"`

I am currently using Xcode 8.2.1 and the project format is Xcode 3.2-compatible.

My understanding based on what I am seeing is that with Swift version 3.0 I shouldn't need to set this? Will setting this do anything that would prevent the code from compiling?

I haven't done a lot with Swift and Xcode differences and I'm having a bit of trouble finding a good explanation of what I should do in this context.

Here's a picture:

[image: Unsupported]

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of hassles moving forward if you just convert the code to Swift 4. It doesn't require nearly as many changes as previous releases, anyway.

Comment: And that’s reasonable in the future perhaps, but I need to test something right now so we can make a change on a server. I want to get the build up ASAP.

Comment: Okay, I just checked, and Xcode 9 does still seem to support Swift 3.2. I notice you're still using Xcode 8; perhaps the version of Swift in this project is too *new* actually? I think Xcode 8 may have only supported Swift 3.1, but my memory may be faulty. Is there a reason you can't update to Xcode 9?

Comment: That may be the case. It appears that Swift 3.2 is included as part of Xcode 9, and 3.1 is included with 8.3.3, and 3.0 with 8.2.1, so I may just need to upgrade my Xcode?

Comment: That's the first thing I'd do.

Comment: Yeah, the developer didn't remember which version of Xcode he used, so I was hoping I could get away with using an older one as I have an older MacBook and didn't want to upgrade my OS, but looks like I'll need to do it.

Comment: I'd upgrade to Xcode 9. But if you have the courage to do this, you probably *could* manually change the setting to Swift 3.1 and work through the build errors. (And for the really courageous, try to submit the app to Apple using Xcode 8.2.1!)

Comment: I’m already in the process of upgrading haha, so I’ll be on High Sierra and Xcode 9 by the end of the night haha

Comment: @dfd Yeah, if you're already willing to go migrate the language, it makes more sense to migrate it *forward* to Swift 4. Otherwise you're just gonna have to do it again sooner or later anyway.

Comment: It’s important I test something by tomorrow morning, so I’m trying to get it tested and working ASAP. I’ll likely decide to upgrade it to Swift 4 going forward but not yet, and maybe not for MVP.

Comment: FYI, Xcode 9 doesn't require High Sierra. I'm still on "simply" Sierra. While I've only heard good things about APFS, I'll wait a few more months - and get a few bootable backups - before taking my "production" Mac up to it. Also, I've done a few "manual" upgrades of Swift 2.x projects to Swift 4. It's a bit tedious, but the Xcode 9 "Fix" is vastly improved over Xcode 8. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you using pod. add following codes end of your podfile . Install pod again hopefully it will works.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Note beforehand: You might have to set the use legacy swift version to true in **every target**, including **every pod**)*

If I were you, I would try using **Xcode 8.1** and set the **use legacy swift version** to **true**. If it not helps, try using the latest version if that doesn't work, then it might be possible, that a **VERY old piece of swift 2** pod or code exists in the project.

We have encountered this problem with Xcode 8. Our project was written in swift 2 and Xcode 8.1 was the latest version that supported that.

**Xcode 9 has swift 3.2 support which is actually swift 3** but only made to make translation to swift 4 easier.

If everything fails, try using the **Code Converter** function of xCode. It has successfully converted our code base from swift 3.0 to swift 4.0.

Note:
Check every pod and its github page to find which pod is too old and you may have to replace that if it is a discounted library.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the answer above, but a bit more complete:

```
# swift 3 and 4 support 
# define pods that use swift 4 here
swift_4 = ['Cosmos-tvOS', 'XCGLogger-tvOS', 'Cosmos-iOS', 'XCGLogger-iOS']

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    swift_version = nil

    if swift_4.include?(target.name)
      swift_version = '4.0'
    else
        swift_version = '3.2'
    end

    if swift_version
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = swift_version
      end
    end
  end
end
```